# Unable to resolve property Fluent nhibernate one to one

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate

```
class CASE
{
   public virtual int ID
   public virtual CASE_BUDGET Case_Budget
}

class CASE_BUDGET
{
   public virtual int Case_Id;
}

class CASE_MAP
{
   Id(x=>x.ID).GeneratedBy.Custom("trigger-identity");
   HasOne<CASE_BUDGET>(x=>x.Case_Budget).Cascade.All();
}

class CASE_BUDGET_MAP
{
   Id(x => x.Case_Id,"CASE_ID").GeneratedBy.Foreign("CASE");
}
```

I received **unable to resolve property:CASE** as my error message when I tried to save a case with a case budget in it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a `HasOne` mapping always needs a corresponding property and `Reference` mapping on the other side (in you case CASE_BUDGET must have a Property referencing the Case). You have to specify it with `.PropertyRef()` or FNH will use the first property which type is of the mapped class.

Comment: I see. So "CASE" in Foreign("CASE") actually refer to "CASE" attribute in CASE_BUDGET class.